# 5v DC +ve connected to 24v negative is this safe?

Tags: voltage, dc

Sorry for this really weird question, but I'm not very knowledgable on electronics.
I have a circuit board that measures rotational speed.
It needs 5v input , and a gnd , and then has a signal output giving 1 pulse per revolution.

My problem is that this signal is input into a controller card which is fed by 24 v

The signal is configured active low in the control card software, and this signal works if I connect it momentarily to the control card 24v -ve.

However when I connect the signal wire from my rotation card to the input pin, it isn't recognised .

I think I should connect the rotation card negative to the control card negative, but I'm afraid to as I don't want to blow something up.

When I tested this connection without actually plugging into the cards, I find that there is a 7.5v reading between the 5v+ and the 24v -ve.
Hence my hesitation as I think the 7.5v will blow up my rotation card.

What the correct way to do this, so that a card with 5v source voltage can pass an active low signal to a card with 24v source voltage

Sorry if this question is asked in an unclear or unprofessional way using the wrong terms.
Please consider that I'm a complete novice with electronics.

I've read a few posts about common ground etc but it's not really making any sense to me right now

Will it be safe to do what I think is right and connect the rotation card GND to the controller card negative so that my input signal can be seen by the controller card software as active low.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is use a 5 V sensor to drive a 24 V "sourcing" input. What this means is that it will source current and to turn it on you just have to short it to ground - as you have discovered.

In Figure 1 below an external sensor is connected to a PLC sourcing input. The PLC input has an opto-coupler to the internal logic to isolate the sensitive logic circuitry from the outside world. (Whether yours does or not doesn't make much difference to the analysis.) The circuit, as far as external switches are concerned, is an LED with series resistor. If we short the input terminal to the common terminal we should expect about 5 to 15 mA to flow (determined by the internal series resistor).

[image: NPN - sourcing input.]

*Figure 1. A sensor with an open-collector output driving a sourcing input powered from a 24 V power source. Note that the negatives are connected.*

Whether this will work with your sensor depends on whether it has an open-collector output or not. If it doesn't damage will occur.

Post a link to the sensor datasheet and post a comment below to let me know.

---

[image]

*Figure 2. The speed signal output circuit seems to read from right to left. Note the internal pull-up to 5 V. This prevents us connecting directly to the 24 V input as shown in Figure 1 as the 24 V will backfeed into the 5 V supply.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flPLsJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 3. Addition of an NPN transistor to buffer the signal between the two boards. This circuit reads left to right.*

How it works:

- With nothing connected to the *Speed signal* output the line will normally be pulled to +5 V by R1. When *OPTO* turns on the line will be pulled to 0 V (GND).
- By adding Q2, any NPN small signal transistor, we can buffer between the 5 V and 24 V circuits. When *OPTO* is off R1 will supply current into the base of Q2 turning it on. Q2 will then short *INPUT* to ground and light the LED.
- When *OPTO* turns on it will steal the current from the base of Q2 which will turn off. This will turn off *INPUT* and the LED.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My sensor is actually a separate circuit board attached to a bldc motor controller, so is quite a complicated circuit, and not a simple sensor as in your diagram . I don't know how to upload files or I could send you the manual I have with both devices which might make more sense to you.

Comment: Otherwise, is it ok to connect a separately powered 5v device to a separately powered 24 v device by connecting the negatives together?

Comment: Take a screengrab of the output stage details and post it in your question. The rest of the circuit doesn't matter. It is (hopefully) represented by "Driver" in my Figure 1.

Comment: Connecting negatives is fine. Connecting the output of one to the input of the other might not be.

Comment: So I've pasted 2 pictures into the post - one shows the control card which I'm using input in6, the other is the rotation control coming from cn12. To get cn12 to function, you have to add 5v power to nc, and fout is the signal Gnd is the question mark I have. Is it ok to connect gnd from cn12 to 0v on the Xhc card, which is already connected to 24v common on my 24v power supply. Sorry if this makes things more confusing

Comment: Please confirm that it's this manual: http://www.cnczone.com/forums/attachments/1/5/5/4/6/1/91748.attach. It seems to be the CN12 circuit on the bottom of page 9 that you are concerned about but the manual shows that as an input and not an output. Tomorrow ...

Comment: Yes that the same thing. The problem with these things are that the manuals are badly translated leading to a lot of confusion on my part anyway. The cn12 is supposed to be an output not an input , as it's where a pulse is supposed to come out for every Rev. Your version of the manual suggests that 5v is coming from cn15, which I have connected and works fine for switching on off spindle reverse etc. However I am also supplying 5v to NC , so if that's not right, what is NC for . Can you tell from that schematic in the manual ? As its all alien to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44290/discussion-between-transistor-and-superllanboy).

Comment: Wow ! This is getting well complicated for my very limited capabilities .

Answer (score 0):

What is used to supply 24V and 5V?
With 7V on the 5V it seems like it needs a load of a few% of rated current to regulate at 5V.

An open collector switch with a Vce rating of 30V or more is suggested with an input current limiting R pullup to 24V seems to be what will work.

More details from you are needed to confirm assumptions.

In any case common supply V- is required for active low activation pulses.

Comment: I have a 24v power supply and a 5 v power supply transformer fed from my 240v mains. These are very similar to computer power supplies , and designed for the job, so no problem here I think. Both are pushing out the correct voltage. When I connect 5v -ve to 24v -ve though, I get 7.5 v between 5v+ and 24v-

Comment: If in addition to connecting 5V(-) to 24V(-) there are also connections labeled GND which are connected, WHAT are those other connections?

Comment: the output may be floating and Earth gnd often reduces EMI but reduces HIPOT insulation strength due to transformer coupling capacitance from common mode lightning pulses. It also allows making the supplies pos. or neg wrt gnd.